# Convert WebService response (XML) to array or list do show on a MVC List

Tags: c#, xml, asp.net-mvc, web-services, serialization

I'm trying to create a web application that gets the response of a webservice (http://servicos.cptec.inpe.br/XML/listaCidades) and store it into a list of cities and then return a ActionResult with a list of cities.

```
<cidades>
    <cidade>
    <nome>São Benedito</nome>
    <uf>CE</uf>
    <id>4750</id>
</cidade>
<cidade>
    <nome>São Benedito do Rio Preto</nome>
    <uf>MA</uf>
    <id>4751</id>
</cidade>
<cidade>
    <nome>São Benedito do Sul</nome>
    <uf>PE</uf>
    <id>4752</id>
</cidade>
<cidade>
    <nome>São Bentinho</nome>
    <uf>PB</uf>
    <id>5845</id>
</cidade>
<cidade>
    <nome>São Bento</nome>
    <uf>MA</uf>
    <id>4753</id>
</cidade>
<cidade>
    <nome>São Bento</nome>
    <uf>PB</uf>
    <id>4754</id>
</cidade>
<cidade>
    <nome>São Bento Abade</nome>
    <uf>MG</uf>
    <id>4755</id>
</cidade>
```

Cidade Class:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Xml.Serialization;

namespace WebApplication1.Models
{
    [Serializable()]
    public class Cidade
    {
        [XmlElement("nome")]
        public string nome { get; set; }
        [XmlElement("uf")]
        public string uf { get; set; }
        [XmlElement("id")]
        [Key]
        public int id { get; set; }
    }
}
```

CidadeCollection Class:

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Xml.Serialization;

namespace WebApplication1.Models
{
    [Serializable()]
    [XmlRoot("cidades")]
    public class CidadeCollection
    {
        [XmlArrayItem(typeof(Cidade))]
        public List<Cidade> cidades = new List<Cidade>();      
    }
}
```

CidadeCollection Controller Class:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Text;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using WebApplication1.Models;
using System.Xml.Serialization;

namespace WebApplication1.Controllers
{
    public class CidadeCollectionController : Controller
    {
        // GET: CidadeCollection
        public ActionResult Index(string s="")
        {
            string conteudo;
            HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://servicos.cptec.inpe.br/XML/listaCidades?city=" + s);
            request.Method = "GET";
            WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();
            CidadeCollection c = new CidadeCollection();
            c.cidades = new List<Cidade>();

            XmlSerializer ser;
            StreamReader reader;

            ser = new XmlSerializer(typeof(List<Cidade>));
            reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream(), Encoding.UTF8);

            c.cidades = (List<Cidade>)ser.Deserialize(reader);
            return View(c.cidades);
        }
    }
}
```

This is the error i get:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M73G5.png)

Comment: Can you please [edit] your question to include the full `ToString()` output of the exception *as text* rather than as a screenshot?  For why, please see [Why not upload images of code on SO when asking a question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/3744182) and [Discourage screenshots of code and/or errors](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/303812/3744182).

Comment: How do i do that? The error says nothing...

Comment: Your services is not responding with XML, That's the problem. Debug your service responses.

Comment: *How do i do that?* Pick `Copiar Detalhes` from the exception dialog, then paste the resulting text into the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, here's a simple way (trivial example, improve as needed):

In your `Controller`:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Xml.Linq;

public ActionResult Foo()
{
    var xml = XDocument.Load("http://servicos.cptec.inpe.br/XML/listaCidades");
    var nodes = xml.Descendants("nome");
    var xElements = nodes as XElement[] ?? nodes.ToArray();
    var foo = new List<string>();
    xElements.ForEach(element => foo.Add(element.Value));
    ViewData["Nomes"] = new SelectList(foo);
    return View();
}
```

In your `View`

```
<h2>Foo</h2>    
@Html.DropDownList("Nomes")
```

Hth..

---

> how can i get the other attributes of "cidade"? like ID and UF to store in a "Cidade" list?

Given your model:

```
public class Cidade
{
    public string nome { get; set; }
    public string uf { get; set; }
    public int id { get; set; }
}
```

Make adjustments to the above like so:

```
var xml = XDocument.Load("http://servicos.cptec.inpe.br/XML/listaCidades");

//all the cidade elements
var nodes = xml.Descendants("cidade");

var xElements = nodes as XElement[] ?? nodes.ToArray();
var foo = new List<Cidade>();

//iterate through the cidade elements and map them to your model
Array.ForEach(xElements, element =>
{       
   foo.Add(new Cidade
   {
        id = int.Parse(element.Element("id").Value), //or TryParse
        nome = element.Element("nome").Value,
        uf = element.Element("uf").Value
    });
});

//foo now has your List (of Cidade)
//do whatever you need to do with it....
foo.ForEach(c => Console.WriteLine($"{c.id} | {c.nome} | {c.uf}"));
```

Hth...

Comment: Man, that looks great! But how can i get the other attributes of "cidade"? like ID and UF to store in a "Cidade" list?

Comment: @ArthuroVerissimo hoping you could have explored `XDocument` on your own given the sample...in any case, updated the answer...